# How do I take off my top track sliding doors?

Tags: wood, doors

How do I take these sliding doors off? There is a post in the middle of them that prevents me lifting them up off the track and angling them out from the bottom.
Thank you in advance
p.s. they are top track only

[image: photo1]

Comment: How is the astragal fixed to the building? Can you unscrew it? Typically sliding doors are removed by lifting a door straight upward, about 1/8th of an inch, and then pulling the door toward yourself, out of the track. The door wont come off its rail until the wheel is lifted out of the track groove.

Comment: If the door slab is held to the suspending bracket only by the three wood screws visible on the back side, then these could be removed from each bracket and the door slab released.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from the fuzzy photo whether the hanging hardware has a release mechanism, but typically you'd just swing the door outward (away from the closet) about 20 degrees, so that the top of the wheel clears the upper track lip, then lift it off. Obviously you'd start with the front (outer) slab.

The post you mentioned shouldn't be an issue. If there's a slide retainer on the floor you'll need to detach it first.

If those rivets I see engage notches in a two-piece hanger, you may have other options. I suspect that they're permanently attached in this case, though. Some have lever releases.

Answer (score 0):

I think @isherwood is correct but if that doesn't work see if you can remove the post. Another option is to unbolt the door from the roller.

Comment: Do you see how the lower channel lip is taller than the upper lip? This is so the door can't be accidentally knocked off the track. It's generally not possible to lift the rollers out in that direction, so the post is immaterial.

Comment: What I though OP meant was when the door is angled out she can't push it up because it hits the post. When it's angled and she lifts it it's actually going into the post. To remove the door it goes into the closet and if the post is too close she can't push it in. I have a similar door, tonight I'm going to look at it to see how a post behind it would affect removing it. OP may be angling too much (and hitting post) or not angling enough.